# How do you explain partial charges in molecules that have a dipole?

Tags: bond, covalent-compounds, dipole

For example if i have hydrogen and fluorine covalently bonded with each other, it would result in a polar molecule with the valence electrons being pulled closer to the fluorine than it is to the hydrogen. At some time the electrons will be at the fluorine end more often as it has higher electronegativity and thus making the hydrogen end partly positive. How does this work? If one electron is pulled to the fluorine end (the one that is shared), doesn't this just revert the hydrogen to its neutral state (as an element) and not be a partly positive charge?

Or does the electrons that are shared also including the lone pairs are going to orbit the shell of the other covalently bonded element, so that in some time there won't be any electrons in one end?

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are describing. The positive nuclear charges attract electrons. More charged nuclei can be expected to attract electrons more strongly, all else being equal (but all else isn't equal because neutral atoms with more highly charged nuclei also have more electrons). Quantum mechanics tells you how those electrons spread about the nuclei. It is the outermost electrons in the valence shell that are shared. The electrons are not localized, their position is described by something called a wavefunction (often represented as orbitals), ...

Comment: ... you can think of the electron probability being smeared about the nuclei.

Comment: I should have written "to a first approximation it is the outermost valence electrons that are shared".

Comment: RE: *If one electron is pulled to the fluorine end (the one that is shared), doesn't this just revert the hydrogen to its neutral state (as an element) and not be a partly positive charge?* Hydrogen only has one electron. So if the fluorine atom pulls that electron away then you're left with $\ce{H+}$.

Answer (score 1):

> At some time the electrons will be at the fluorine end more often as it has higher electronegativity and thus making the hydrogen end partly positive. How does this work?

This is the charge distribution on the "surface" of the HF molecule, estimated by the program molcalc.org:

[image]

In a thought experiment, if you placed a negative sample charge (ideally with less charge than the elementary charge of the electron to not mess with the electron distribution) on the surface of the molecule, it would feel a force that is color coded in the picture (blue and cyan - attractive, red and yellow - repulsive). If you go sufficiently far away, the sample charge would not have any interaction because the molecule is net neutral. On the other hand, if you approach either nucleus, the sample charge would experience strong attraction (so the fluorine nucleus is not negative, even though we correctly assign the fluorine atom a negative partial charge).

To get a quantitative measure of the partial charge, you have to divide the space into two parts - that "belonging" to fluorine and that "belonging" to hydrogen. Then, you can sum up the charges due to the electrons and compare it to the nuclear charge.

> If one electron is pulled to the fluorine end (the one that is shared), doesn't this just revert the hydrogen to its neutral state (as an element) and not be a partly positive charge?

Two electrons are shared. If you start with atoms, electron density from both atoms moves toward the center of the bond (very little, surprisingly, and drawing a stick for a bond is not very realistic but is great for counting electrons).

Your idea is that one electron is pulled to the fluorine. This is a very simple model, but let's explore it a bit. In this picture, the electron "originating from the hydrogen" would still be involved in binding, so we are not back to atoms.

What really happens is that instead of being spherically distributed around atoms, the electron distribution changes a bit when the bond is formed, with the bonding orbital (in the simplest valence bond or molecular orbital model) having electrons occupy the space near either nucleus, but not in a symmetric way. That leads to the charge separation.

> Or does the electrons that are shared also including the lone pairs are going to orbit the shell of the other covalently bonded element, so that in some time there won't be any electrons in one end?

I did not understand this scenario. Maybe edit the question to clarify before it gets closed.

Comment: Do the blue, green and red regions represent charge distribution $δ^{+}$ or $δ^{-}$ or the electrostatic potential which is related to the partial charges?

Comment: Red is negative, blue is positive and green neutral potential. Based on that you would assign negative partial charge to fluorine and positive to hydrogen. For a quantitative treatment, you would have to integrate over areas belonging to either atom.

Comment: Apologised if I was misunderstood. What troubles me is the interpretation of the coloring. Does it denote partial charge or electric potentital?

Comment: @Anton Electostatic potential

Answer (score 0):

In a covalent bond, it is true that if one atom is more electronegative than the other atom, there will be creation of charges, (negative on the more electronegative atom). But, it doesn't mean that the shared electron will only stick towards Fluorine (in your case) which is more electronegative. The shared electron will also revolve around the other less electronegative atom, i.e., Hydrogen (which is less electronegative).

So, it will **not** revert back Hydrogen into neutral state, moreover due to covalent bond energy between Fluorine and Hydrogen this is highly unlinkely (without any external stimuli).

Check [this](https://manoa.hawaii.edu/exploringourfluidearth/chemical/properties-water/types-covalent-bonds-polar-and-nonpolar) to understand the concept clearly!